# VirtualBox, internet access via guest OS (Windows)

Tags: windows, linux, networking, virtualbox

I have an USB internet key (multimode GPRS/EDGE/UMTS/HSDPA) that only works on Windows.

Though, I mainly use Linux for development activities and I don't want to move them to Windows. For this reason I decided to use a Windows guest on VirtualBox for internet access and the Linux host for the other stuffs, but I'd greatly prefer to use Linux for everything (internet too) and Windows only as internet gateway.

How could I setup such environment? Any instructions or links to documentation are appreciated.

Host: Ubuntu 10.10 LTS
Guest: Windows XP,
VirtualBox: an old version but I can upgrade.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by “internet key“? What technology is your internet connection based on? (dsl, cable, 3g?)  Maybe we can come up with a solution so that you can connect directly from linux.

Comment: It's an usb internet key multimode GPRS/EDGE/UMTS/HSDPA. (I edited the question adding this detail, HTH).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest upgrading to the latest version of VirtualBox from http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads. You will also need to install the extension pack listed below the main downloads. The extension pack is installed by going to File->preferences->extensions->'add package button'

this adds USB support.

next you need to configure your VirtualBox to pass-through your wireless USB key to the virtual.

On top of this you will need to configure your virtual guest network adapter to have one Host-only adapter.

next boot up your virtual and make sure your USB key is recognized and working fine with the internet. Then you will need to find your network adapter Explorer page and highlight both the VirtualBox network adapter AND the wireless one. right click it and select bridge network adapters.